# A reasonable level of security vs. sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm getting ready to launch a site - the first one that I coded from the ground up. It's going to be low traffic, and low-profile (probably won't get spidered by search engines.) I'm using PEAR's DB library and its query() method's placeholders to store user data, as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('db.inc');
$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$rsvp = $_POST['rsvp'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$lodging = $_POST['lodging'];
$extra = $_POST['extra'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;

if (isset($id)) {
  $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE guest SET username = ?, mail = ?, phone = ?, lodging = ?, extra = ?, msg = ?, role = ?, password = ?, mailed = ? WHERE id = ?", array($username, $mail, $phone, $lodging,$extra, $msg, 2, $password, 0, $id)); //TODO!! set mailed to 1 in production
  } else {
  $sql = $conn->query('INSERT INTO guest (username, password, rsvpstatus, role, mail, phone, lodging, extra, msg, mailed)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', array($username, $password, $rsvp,  2, $mail, $phone, $lodging, $extra, $msg, 1));
  }

 header('location:main.php');
```

Does this seem like a reasonable level of protection vs sql injection?

Comment: I'd always run into problems when I inserted a new token higher in the sql query text and bump the order of the parameters around, ended up writing my own function that would use the index on the param order to replace tokens like {0},{1},{2} etc in the sql query, it also permitted me to have multiple of the same token around my query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placeholders and binding like you are doing are exactly the defense against sql injection. As long as you never directly interpolate any user input into the sql, you're fine.

Comment: +1, prepared statements are 100% injection proof if they're used for every query on a site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **mysql_real_escape_string** function in PHP ([view function in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))

> Escapes special characters in the
>   unescaped_string, taking into account
>   the current character set of the
>   connection so that it is safe to place
>   it in a mysql_query()

Example:

```
$secure_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['firstname'] );
$secure_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['lastname'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as that library quotes and escapes all of its arguments, it will be fine.